# In what order are weights saved in a LSTM kernel in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I looked into the saved weights for a `LSTMCell` in Tensorflow. 
It has one big kernel and bias weights.

The dimensions of the kernel are

```
(input_size + hidden_size)*(hidden_size*4)
```

Now from what I understand this is encapsulating 4 input to hidden layer affine transforms as well as 4 hidden to hidden layer transforms.

So there should be 4 matrices of size

```
input_size*hidden_size
```

and 4 of size

```
hidden_size*hidden_size
```

Can someone tell me or point me to the code where TF saves these, so I can break the kernel matrix into smaller matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weights are combined as mentioned in the other answer, but the order is: 
where `c` is the context and `h` is the history.

```
input_c,      input_h
new_input_c,  new_input_h
forget_c,     forget_h
output_c,     output_h
```

The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L565)

```
if self._state_is_tuple:
  c, h = state
else:
  c, h = array_ops.split(value=state, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=one)

gate_inputs = math_ops.matmul(
    array_ops.concat([inputs, h], 1), self._kernel)
gate_inputs = nn_ops.bias_add(gate_inputs, self._bias)

# i = input_gate, j = new_input, f = forget_gate, o = output_gate
i, j, f, o = array_ops.split(
    value=gate_inputs, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=one)
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. I also found the same order here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/lstm_ops.h#L248

Answer (score 2):

In tensorflow 1.5, LSTM variables are defined in `LSTMCell.build` method. The source code can be found in [`rnn_cell_impl.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L713):

```py
self._kernel = self.add_variable(
    _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME,
    shape=[input_depth + h_depth, 4 * self._num_units],
    initializer=self._initializer,
    partitioner=maybe_partitioner)
self._bias = self.add_variable(
    _BIAS_VARIABLE_NAME,
    shape=[4 * self._num_units],
    initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer(dtype=self.dtype))
```

As you can see, there's just one `[input_depth + h_depth, 4 * self._num_units]` variable, not 8 different matrices, and all of them are multiplied simultaneously in a batch.

The gates are defined this way:

```py
i, j, f, o = array_ops.split(value=gate_inputs, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=one)
```